# Powershell Read File, search $$I and Replace, write file?

Tags: powershell, search

cane someone Help me a bit.
I want to read a Text file, Search for `$$I` and replace it with the current Dir Name, Then write the file again.
Well something does not work :(

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("CC.comp")
$content = $content -replace '$$I','Split-Path -Path (Get-Location) -Leaf'
Print $content
pause
```

Comment: In short: PowerShell's `-replace` operator is _regex_-based. To use a search string literally, any regex metacharacters (e.g. `.`, `*` and `+`) must be ``\``-escaped, either individually, or by calling `[regex]::Escape()` on the string as a whole.
Alternatively, instead of the `-replace` _operator_, you can use the .NET `.Replace()` _method_, which performs _literal_ substring searches and replacements on string objects, albeit case-_sensitively_ by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-replace` uses [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3) and `$` is a special regex character which needs to be escaped with `\` if you want to match it literally:

```bash
'$$I' -replace '$$I', 'test'    # Nothing is replaced
'$$I' -replace '\$\$I', 'test'  # Outputs 'test'
```

However, much easier is to use the [`.Replace` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) for literal replacement, no escaping is needed:

```bash
(Get-Content CC.comp -Raw).Replace('$$I', (Split-Path $pwd -Leaf)) |
    Set-Content CC.comp
```